# How to get one video in jsp page. If any one are available. If both video available pick only one video?

Tags: html, jsp

```
 <div class="flashDiv">
                <object class="flashObject">
                    <param name="movie" value="${baseURL}${viewDemo.activityId}.swf">
                    <embed src="${baseURL}${viewDemo.activityId}.swf" class="flashObject">
                    </embed>
                </object>

            </div>
```

My system /var/video/  having two vedio (1.swf) & (1.mp4)

I want to get any one video in jsp page. (if any one are available ).
In case both video available only one(either mp4 or swf) is view in jsp.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using html5 `video` tag

```
<video width="480">
  <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="video2.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="video3.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
</video>
```

See more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) at mozilla developer site.

**NOTE:**
Currently html5 does n't provide support for swf format.